# Attachment displays twice on notes document

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a lotusscript function that creates new documents containing an attachment in a richtext file.

```
    ...
    Dim docProcess As NotesDocument
    Set docProcess = dbCurrent.createDocument
    docProcess.form = "result"
    ...
    'Attach file
    Dim rtfFile As NotesRichTextItem
    Set rtfFile = docProcess.Createrichtextitem("xmlFile")
    Call rtfFile.Embedobject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", filePath + fileName, "file")

    Call docProcess.save(False, False)
```

My form design looks like this

[image: Form design]

$V2AttachmentOptions is computed for display, value "0"
xmlFile is a (editable) richtext field

However, when opening the document in the Notes client, it looks like this:

[image: Screen shot of Notes Client representation]

We are using Notes V9.01 FP8

How can I hide the attachment displayed below the line?

I found [this](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21089682) technote, but that is not related, since I don't open the doc in edit mode (it is created on the server by an agent).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not including the fourth parameter? The Designer manual says that it's to be used with OLE/2 objects, not for attachments. The example in the technote contradicts this, but on the other hand I have created many scripts for attachments without the fourth parameter and it's always worked as intended.